# Changing system-level dialogs: TimePicker, DatePicker

Tags: android, user-interface

I have HTC Hero, and i see that TimePickerDialog and DatePickerDialog were changed by HTC (they look different than those in the emulator).

My question is how can i change such system level dialogs?

Answer (score 3):

Write your own firmware, including those mods, and deploy them on your own handsets (either that you manufacture or those that support flashing alternative firmware).

Comment: Can you pls be more verbose - are those dialogs part of android that a programmer cannot change without producing firmware? I.e. what changes in the firmware are needed?

Comment: "are those dialogs part of android that a programmer cannot change without producing firmware?" Yes. "what changes in the firmware are needed?" The `TimePickerDialog` and `DatePickerDialog` classes, apparently, since those are the ones you want to change.